# php-like constructor in javascript object

Tags: javascript

Is in javascript possible to create php-like constructor?

I mean, in php you can do this

```
<?php

class myObj
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        print "Hello world!";
    }
}

//prints "Hello world!"
new myObj();
```

I have been playing with such an idea in JS. Is that even possible?

```
var myObj = function()
{
    this.prototype.constructor = function()
    {
        console.log("Hello world!");
    }
}

//I'd like to execute some actions without invoking further methods
//This should write "Hello world! into the console
new myObj();
```

Comment: you would put that code in the function itself, aka the constructor function.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
var myObj = function() {
    console.log("Hello world!");
}
new myObj();
```

There is no separate constructor, this *is* the constructor. The difference between `myObj()` and `new myObj()` (explanation by request (not guaranteed to be better than our custom pizzas)) is that the later will do weird stuff with `this`. A more complex example:

```
var myObj = function() {
    this.myProperty = 'whadever';
}
new myObj(); //Gets an object with myProperty set to 'whadever' and __proto__(not that you should use it, use Object.getPrototypeOf()) set to 'myObj'.
```

It works by substituting `this` for the new object. So it makes a new object (`{}`) and sees `theNewAwesomeObject.myProperty = 'whatever'`. Since there is no non-primitive return value, `theNewAwesomeObject` is automatically returned. If we did just `myObj()`, without `new` it wouldn't auto return, so it would have the return value of `undefined`.

Comment: How is `new myObj()` different from just doing `myObj()`? You should probably explain this briefly in your answer.

Comment: @dandavis I do. That was just an example of what the OP or an other user might ask.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite pattern:

```
function Cat(){
   console.log("Cat!");
}
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
```

Then create it like this:

```
var foo = new Cat();
```

Comment: thats how "The coding train" would have taught you!

Answer (score 0):

You can have an immediately invoked function:

```
function MyObject() {
    var _construct = function() {
        console.log("Hello from your new object!");
    }();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqP9x/